# Replacement for descendant-or-self in XPath/XQuery

Tags: xpath, xquery, marklogic

I'm looking out a replacement for `descendant-or-self` in XPath/XQuery. We use XQuery for querying MarkLogic DB. The reason why I want a replacement for `descendant-or-self` is I'm trying to match say 50 values against a attribute value in an XML structure. The XML says it has more than 1 million nodes, so I had to do descendant-or-self 1 million times each time to find the exact matching node, which is very costly operation. The basic XML hierarchy is given below

A (@val=1) -> B (@Val="2") -> C (@val="3") -> A -> A -> A -> A(indefinite)

Above I'm trying to match the `val` attribute in each node to find the exact node. As the `A` node is occurring in different levels after `C` i'm not able to use any MarkLogic APIs to find exact matching node as I'm not aware at which level in XML its matching. (Assume fragmentation is done at B level)

Comment: Please provide the XPath that's slow.

Comment: Is this your current XPath: `A[@val=1]/B[@Val="2"]/C[val="3"]//A` ?

Comment: You say *The XML says it has more than 1 million nodes, so I had to do descendant-or-self 1 million times* -- this is a remarkable non sequitur.  Can you explain?

Answer (score 5):

The problem may be fragmentation and XML structure rather than the descendant-or-self axis as such. Crossing fragment boundaries in XPath has a cost, and even a small cost adds up fast with a million fragments. MarkLogic works best if you think of documents as rows, not tables.

Before you do anything else, I'd suggest profiling the slow query. Get the output from `xdmp:query-meters()` after evaluating your XPath. That will tell you how many fragments the XPath has to traverse.

Once you've confirmed that it's fragmentation, there are several options. You could try renaming the root-level `A` element to something else, so that `//A` does not match the root. That way the XPath should not have to cross fragment boundaries. However you may still run into problems any time some other XPath crosses that fragment boundary.

My preferred solution would be to break up the document so that you have a million `B` documents rather than a single `A` with a million `B` child fragments. Any information at the root `A` level would have to be duplicated in every `B` root, or possibly moved into a small manifest document at a well-known URI.

I think that's as specific as I can get without seeing the content and perhaps hearing some user stories.